# Ktor Session Cookie Authentication

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'd like to use a session cookie for authentication with Ktor and what I have so far is:

```
private const val SEVER_PORT = 8082
private const val SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "some-cookie-name"

data class AuthSession(
    val authToken: String
)

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = SEVER_PORT, module = Application::basicAuthApplication).start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.basicAuthApplication() {
    install(Sessions) {
        cookie<AuthSession>(SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, SessionStorageMemory()) {
            cookie.path = "/"
        }
    }
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(Authentication) {
        session<AuthSession> {
            validate { session ->
                // TODO: do the actual validation
                null
            }
        }
    }

    routing {
        authenticate {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("Success")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But everytime when I do:

```
curl -v localhost:8082
```

I get an HTTP 200 and the response "Success"

I expected to get an HTTP 401 Not authorized or something similar.

Can somebody give me insights here how to do proper session cookie authentication with Ktor?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Okay I realized there is a `session` auth type which is not documented with  authentication feature docs.

The issue with your current code is that you are not specifying the `challenge` explicitly, the default challenge specified inside is `SessionAuthChallenge.Ignore` so you have to change it to `SessionAuthChallenge.Unauthorized` or `SessionAuthChallenge.Redirect`

So your code should look like:

```
install(Authentication) {
    session<AuthSession> {
        challenge = SessionAuthChallenge.Unauthorized
        validate { session ->
            // TODO: do the actual validation
            null
        }
    }
}
```

**OLD:**

You are not specifying the type of authentication you want to use, probably `basic`, `form` or `jwt`, you may want to try something like this for form authentications for example:

```
install(Authentication) {
    form("login") {

        skipWhen { call -> call.sessions.get<AuthSession>() != null }

        userParamName = "username"
        passwordParamName = "password"
        challenge = FormAuthChallenge.Unauthorized
        validate { credentials ->
         // Handle credentials validations
       }
    }
}
```

Check the [official documentation](https://ktor.io/servers/features/authentication.html) for more info.

Comment: Hm, what what is this then:
```
install(Authentication) {
        session<AuthSession> {
            validate { session ->
                // TODO: do the actual validation
                null
            }
        }
    }``` ?

Comment: Cool. `challenge = SessionAuthChallenge.Unauthorized` did the trick. Thx

Comment: I tried this w/ 1.3.2 of Ktor but no go as it looks like challenge implementation has changed since last year, has anyone seen any examples of the latest implementation for Authentication challenges? It behaves like it's still defaulting to Ignore but it's not clear how to set it in the pipeline.